# VS Code private field false positive warnings "variable is declared but its value is never read."

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

There is false positive warnings like "variable is declared but its value is never read."

```
class Account {
    // Public field(s) -> instances
    local = navigator.language;

    // Private field(s)
    #movements = [];
    #pin;

    constructor(owner, currency, pin) {
      this.owner = owner;
      this.currency = currency;
      this.#pin = pin;

      console.log(`Thanks for opening an account, ${owner}!`);
    }

    getMovements() {
      return this.#movements;`your text`
    }

    deposit(val) {
      this.#movements.push(val);
    }

    withdraw(val) {
      this.deposit(-val);
    }
}

const marko = new Account('Marko', 'EUR', 1111);
console.log(marko.pin);
```

A private method declared like #pin is used in the constructor, but VS Code does not recognise that it is used.

[image]

Comment: `#pin` is never used inside the class. Notice, that you can't access a private property outside of the class, that's the idea of private properties.

Comment: @TamilSelvanC — Why are you making that recommendation? Are you aware of some bug in earlier versions of VS Code which would cause this problem (not that there is a problem since the error message isn't a false positive). Do you have some reason to assume that the OP's copy of VS Code is out of date (which seems unlikely given that a typical install will self-updated automatically).

Answer (score 6):

The error says "**is never read**".

The line you refer to (`this.#pin = pin;`) doesn't **read** it. It **writes** to it.

It looks like `console.log(marko.pin);` might be an attempt to read it, but it fails because its a **private** member.